# What is the file format/encoding of this binary data stream

Tags: file-format, dataformat, audioformat

I have some binary blobs (`blob` from MySQL). These are suppose to be an audio stream recorded using JS web-app.

I took one of these blobs and save it as `a.wtf` file. When I ran `strings a.wtf`, I get some useful information.

```
webmB
QTmuxingAppLibWebM-0.0.1WA
QTwritingAppLibWebM-0.0.1
A_OPUSc
OpusHead
OPUS
...
```

I also tried the following in the terminal (tips on google).

```
[dilawars@chutki data (master)]$ mkvextract a.wtf tracks 0:audio.opus
Error: (mkvextract) The file 'a.wtf' could not be opened for reading: Not a valid Matroska file (no segment/level 0 element found).
```

[Download a.wtf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hVILY_-pt6bZvIZ5u2mYPXI1DGl4qZ5/view?usp=sharing).

Any help is very much appreciated? Ideally, I'd like to convert them to WAV format.

**Update**

I used this [tool](https://hachoir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
[dilawars@chutki data (master)]$ hachoir-metadata a.wtf 
[err!] Unable to parse file: a.wtf
```

Comment: It appears to be a WebM file containing Opus audio, but it is corrupt, it seems to be encoded in text when it should be binary.

Comment: @bryc thanks. Its base64 encoded. I used FFmpeg to convert it to WAV file. Worked flawlessly. Thanks again for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tip by @bryc, I managed to find a solution. The data in MySQL is in base64 encoding (uploaded file `a.wtf` is already in binary format). I decode them back to a binary stream and saved it as `a.webm` file. After that, I ran the following command.

```sh
$ ffmpeg -i a.webm -ac 1 -f wav -vn -ar 20500 a.wav
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out; although that a.wtf file doesn't appear to be in any base64 representation I'm aware of. How did you decode the a.wtf file back to binary?

Comment: @bryc Uploaded file is already in binary format. My bad. I'll make a  note.